# Boost libraries in netbeans 7.1.1

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, configure

I need help for compiling and configuring boost libraries in netbeans 7.1.1 ,let me add to it that i did add the path where the boost zip folder is extracted in the compiler options but it didnt help me out and when i included

```
  #include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

while compiling it resulted an error as

```
  fatal error :no such file or directory
```

Just to add to it when i wrote:-

```
  #include <boost/thread.hpp>//does shows the options out of which thread.hpp is one
```

any help folks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost::thread requires a compiled library in addition to the header file. (I am assuming you are using Windows and have the netbeans c++ plugin) To compile the library for netbeans, you need to use cygwin and follow the steps found on [boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary), using the `toolset=gcc` flag along with any other flags you need when calling `b2 install`. For each step, try `--help` before you run the command.